# django mail queue emails not sending with celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm using [Django Mail Queue](https://pypi.org/project/django-mail-queue/) with **Django 2.x**

The application is hosted on **Heroku** and using **redis** backend for **Celery**

The **settings.py** file contains

```
##################
# CELERY STUFF
##################
BROKER_URL = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

#######################
# Django mail queue
#######################
MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True
MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP = False
```

and sending email like

```
new_message = MailerMessage()
new_message.subject = subject
new_message.to_address = to
new_message.from_address = from_email
new_message.content = text_content
new_message.html_content = html_content
new_message.app = 'Koober'
new_message.save()
```

On sending the email, it is saved in the database and is shown on the Admin page but is not sent.

Setting `MAILQUEUE_CELERY = False` and `MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP = False` is sending email successfully.

But this is resulting in application failure in case of an exception. That's why I want to use **Celery** to send email in the background.

[image]

**app/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'koober.settings')
app = Celery('koober')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: Are there any errors in Celery logs? Did you try to run another simple task with Celery?

Comment: I have a **celery.py** file created at **app/celery.py** (updated in question). How can I log the celery log. I'm using **Celery** for the first time.

Comment: I think that might be an issue as Celery should be running as a separate process. Read there how to run it in another terminal tab http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Comment: Are you actually sending the messages that are queued? `python manage.py send_queued_messages`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid This works. When executed in **heroku** `heroku run python manage.py send_queued_messaged`. So, do I need to run the command as **Cron**?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://django-mail-queue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> A cron job can be set up to work one of two ways: using a management
>   command or an HTTP request. Both methods run the mail queue which
>   grabs emails and sends them. To decrease load, it only tries to send
>   30 emails at a time. This number can be changed by using
>   MAILQUEUE_LIMIT in settings

The idea is that the messages are queued up for sending, and you have to manually trigger the workers to send messages. The preferred method is to do this by running the `send_queued_messages` management command:

```
python manage.py send_queued_messages
```

From your comment:

> As per this line in the documentation *Instead of using the cron job
>   the celery task worker will attempt to send email when it’s saved. The
>   cron job will clean up any emails that get lost.* I do not need to run
>   the management command when `MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True.`

By default, the application doesn't need celery to work. It works synchronously (at the same time) - which is how the default mail functionality of django works.

As soon as the application reaches the code to send mail, it will attempt to send mail and pause until it gets a response, then continue with the rest of the request.

The other option is to defer sending of the email and instead of using the same process as the web, use a secondary process (the worker) at the same time. This is what happens when you set `MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True`.

If you set `MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP = True` as you have done, now messages are accepted but queued, and you must use the management command or cron to send messages.

So, if you want messages to be sent immediately, set `MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP` to `False`.

If you want to send messages in batches in intervals, set `MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP` to `True`, and then setup a cron job to run the management command.

Comment: But I can't run the management command every time. So, I need to set **Cron** job to run this command?

Comment: As per this line in the documentation `Instead of using the cron job the celery task worker will attempt to send email when it’s saved. The cron job will clean up any emails that get lost.` I do not need to run the management command when **MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True**.

Comment: I noticed that even **mangement** command is not able to send messages when **MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True**. Not even after adding to queue from admin interface.

Comment: If you use synchronous mode (the default), then it will send automatically. However, you are using asynchronous (queuing) which means you need to send the batches manually by the management command.

Comment: Yeah I got your concept. But in my case, I have `MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True` and `MAILQUEUE_QUEUE_UP = False`. So, it should be sending email asynchronously in background instead of queueing up and waiting for management command. But it neither send on save nor on management command when `MAILQUEUE_CELERY = True`

Comment: Well, it won't send with management command since there is nothing queued to be released. Are you sure your workers are running?